# How to serialize/deserialize enum column in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mybatis, mybatis-plus

I am using [spring boot](https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot) (with bundled jackson and lombok), [mybatis](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/getting-started.html) and [mybatis-plus](https://baomidou.com/en/guide/quick-start.html#dependency).

I have a model `User` with an enum column `status`:

```
import com.baomidou.mybatisplus.annotation.EnumValue;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonValue;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;

@AllArgsConstructor
public enum UserStatusEnum {
  ACTIVE(1, "active"),
  INACTIVE(0, "inactive");

  @EnumValue
  private Integer dbValue;
  @JsonValue
  private String jsonValue;
}

import com.baomidou.mybatisplus.annotation.TableField;
import com.baomidou.mybatisplus.annotation.TableName;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@TableName(value = "users")
public class User {
  Integer id;
  UserStatusEnum status = UserStatusEnum.ACTIVE;
  String username;
  @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", timezone = "UTC")
  LocalDateTime createdAt = LocalDateTime.now();
}
```

Database schema is like

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    status TINYINT NOT NULL,
    username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
)  ENGINE=INNODB;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX users_username_unique ON users (username);
INSERT INTO users (status, username) VALUES (1, "test")
```

I want to get a user with status of string in json like `{"id":1,"status":"active","username":"test","createdAt":"2021-12-08T00:00:00.000Z"}` and `status` is stored in database as `TINYINT` 1. How can I get that?

I am using mapper:

```
import com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.mapper.BaseMapper;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Mapper;

@Mapper
public interface UserMapper extends BaseMapper<User> {}
```

and make call like:

```
@Component
public class UserService {
  @Autowired
  UserMapper userMapper;

  public User findUser(Integer id) {
    return userMapper.selectById(id);
  }
}
```

Right now I would have error like this:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path []
  threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is
  org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is
  org.apache.ibatis.executor.result.ResultMapException:
  Error attempting to get column 'status' from result set.
  Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
  No enum constant app.model.user.UserStatusEnum.1] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant app.model.user.UserStatusEnum.1
```

Comment: And how do you query the data?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Updated, there is automatic api from mybatis-plus to select one record

Comment: Without more information, I assume that it's using the `EnumTypeHandler` instead of the `EnumOrdinalHandler` (since it's attempting `UserStatusEnum.1` instead of looking up by `ordinal()`.  Without knowing how exactly you're configuring mybatis you'll need to look into the type handlers https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#typeHandlers